# Why my instrumental tests is not able to find a resource from other module?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a multimodule project which has a moduleA and a moduleB which depends from moduleA. Everything works well but I just implemented an instrumentalTest in moduleB to cover an UI functionality (jetpack compose) from moduleB but I'm getting the follwing error:

`android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f100135`

The resource which is failing is defined in moduleA, besides I have the following code defined in  moduleB:

```
implementation(project(Modules.moduleA))
androidTestImplementation(project(Modules.moduleA))
```

I found a workaround which is copy the resource to the androidTest folder from moduleB but I would prefer don't do that. I'm running out of ideas...

[image]